# Access function to hide controls on a form

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

ACCESS 2016

I am trying to create a function to hide controls that are passed to it.

I have a textbox called NextCheck. I have the function:

```
Public Function hideControl(ctrl As Control)
Set ctrl.Visible = False
End Function
```

And the Sub on the form below.

```
Private Sub testBtn_Click()
hideControl (Me.Nextcheck)
End Sub
```

When I run this I get a message

> 'run-time error '424' Object required

Can anyone point me in the right direction (I'm a novice with functions) as to what the problem is here. My understanding that the (Me.Nextcheck) was the object being passed to the function.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis and remove the word `Set` and change the `Function` to `Sub`

Comment: What braX said, + remove the parentheses (`hideControl (Me.Nextcheck)` should be `hideControl Me.Nextcheck`). Also note that a function with just one line of code is a bad practice imho, you might as well just type that one line instead of the function call and it probably will be more clear later/for others

Comment: Is the form in continuous or datasheet view? Setting the Visible property will be reflected for all instances of control, i.e. the same result for all records. Can use Conditional Formatting to enable/disable textboxes/comboboxes.